# php access static member by variable class name

Tags: php, class, static, yii

Now I am working with yii framework and I'd like to wrote something like this:

```
protected static $model = "Customer";
...
public function actionIndex() {
    $model::model()->find(...
```

Now it works:

```
protected static $model = "Customer";
protected static $model_obj;
...
public function __construct($controller, $id) {
    $this->model_obj = new self::$model;
...
public function actionIndex() {
    $model_obj::model()->find(...
```

but creating object for access static member is a bad thing.
how to avoid it?

getClass takes object as first parameter and it is not suitable for this purpose

google say:

```
$a = constant($myClassName . "::CONSTANT");
$b = call_user_func(array($myClassName, "static_method"));
```

it looks like a horrible peace of shit. using this may make many troubles. another solution?

oh! my problem was another:

```
$controller::$NAME::model() // error

$controller_name = $controller::$NAME
$controller_name::model() // good
```

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
class foo
{
  public static function bar()
  {
    return 42;
  }
}

// class name as string

$class = 'foo';

var_dump($class::bar()); // 42

// method name as string

$method = 'bar';

var_dump(foo::$method()); // 42

// class AND method names as strings

var_dump($class::$method()); // 42
```

Comment: If this answered your posted question, please remember to accept as the answer and post your other problem in a new question (so that it may help other users as well)

Answer (score 0):

```
call_user_func(array($myClassName, "static_method"));
```

Is the primary way to do it. I'm not quite sure why this would cause any problems.

Comment: compare call_user_func(array("Customer", "read", $id)); with Customer::read($id) =(